# Finding the tab that fired an http-on-examine-response event

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm using the nsIObserverService to monitor the responses, but it fires events for all tabs (browser in Mozilla terminology). I'd like to know which browser is getting the response in my observe method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [sample code snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification) from DevMo should do the trick. It allows you to find a browser (tab) given an `nsICHannel` from an HTTP request/response.

It specifically references the `http-on-modify-request` event, but `aSubject` should still be an `nsIChannel` for `http-on-examine-response event` events.

Comment: I found that it works fine for events fired by the browser, but sometimes fail when the event was fired from a plugin (like Flash). In these cases, nsIChannel will have no notificationCallbacks, making impossible to find the tab that fired the event.