# Firefox equivalent of Transition Qualifiers within Chrome

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

Can you guys kindly point me to an object/api by which i can extract/access referrer information of a page.

Things like:
1) Referrer Url (I am already able to extract it)
2) path to current page (i.e. by clicking a link/ form submit in referrer page or through address bar)
3) whether user arrived at this page by clicking backward/forward button

For google chrome, I understand that the above information can be extracted through transition qualifiers (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html).

I would be most grateful if i am pointed to the right url / source within mozilla docs (not able to find it :().

Comment: You may find some answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16583340/1385896)