# Intercept new downloads in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have written a simple download manager for Windows and I would like to create an addon for Firefox that when enabled intercepts new downloads in Firefox and sends them to the download manager.

I have already done this for **Google Chrome** using:

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(details) {
    // stop the download
    chrome.downloads.cancel(details.id, null);
}
```

The question is how can I achieve something similar using the **Firefox add-on SDK**.

I see there is a way of intercepting page loads to view the content / headers which might be helpful but then I won't know if the request will turn into a download or not.

[Firefox add-on SDK: Get http response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583340/firefox-add-on-sdk-get-http-response-headers)

I could perhaps look for a content type that is not text/html or check for a content disposition header but that could cause problems if I don't correctly handle all cases.

Is there no way of accessing the download manager using the JS SDK or some way of knowing when a download has been started / being started and stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `http-on-examine-response` observer that the linked question discusses is the wrong way to go. It concerns all requests not just downloads.

Instead use the [`Downloads.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#Observing_downloads) to observe new downloads, then cancel them, and so on.

To load `Downloads.jsm` in the SDK use:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");
```

Then you can add your listener.

```
let view = {
  onDownloadAdded: function(download) { 
    console.log("Added", download);
  },
  onDownloadChanged: function(download) {
    console.log("Changed", download);
  },
  onDownloadRemoved: function(download) {
    console.log("Removed", download);
  }
};

Task.spawn(function() {
  try {
    let list = yield Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);
    yield list.addView(view);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
});
```

The linked MDN docs have more information and samples.

Since your add-on is a restartless SDK add-on, you'll need to remove the listener again using `.removeView` on unload, or else there will be a memory leak.

Comment: that looks exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for but I've just run a quick test copying that into my code and trying to download a file but I never see the "Added", "Changed" or "Removed" entries in the log?

Comment: never mind, I it is working now that you added the yield list.addView(view); line

Comment: @miked, there was a syntax error in the code apparently. That's what you get for re-appropriating sample code from the docs :p I fixed that and improved the sample a bit and made sure it does actually work ;)

Comment: Alright, also fixed the broken sample code in MDN (I hope) :p

Comment: perfect, once I have the download I can cancel it and remove it from the list.. the only thing I am not sure about is how I should remove the view on unload to stop the memory leak? I'm very new to FF extension development

Comment: Removed es-6 fat-arrow functions, to not make @Noitidart's head explode LOL

Comment: @miked, unload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload#exports.onUnload%28%29

Comment: But this still shows Firefox's default download dialog. Please take a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141782/intercept-download-link-click-and-prevent-default-download-dialog

Answer (score 2):

Here's the JSM way.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var view = {
    onDownloadChanged: function (download) {
        console.log(download, 'Changed');
        if (download.succeeded) {
            var file = new FileUtils.File(this.target.path);
            console.log('file', file);
        }
    }
};

var list;
Task.spawn(function () {
    list = yield Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);
    list.addView(view);
}).then(null, Components.utils.reportError);
```

Remember to `removeView` to stop listening. Can do this anywhere, like in `shutdown` function or whatever, doesn't have to be within that `Task.spawn` so `list` must be global var.

```
list.removeView(view); //to stop listening
```

Here's the old way, which seems to still work. Although I thought they said they're going to take out the old downloadManager:

```
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/download-manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIDownloadManager);

observerService.addListener({
    onDownloadStateChange: function (state, dl) {
        console.log('dl=', dl);
        console.log('state=', state);
        console.log('targetFile', dl.targetFile);
        if (state == 7 && dl.targetFile.leafName.substr(-4) == ".txt") {
            //guys just downloaded (succesfully) a .txt file
        }
    }
});
```

Heres a mozillazine with some more on this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2792021